# Channel causes panic when called on same scope

Tags: go

Can someone explain to me why the first code runs but the second one fails?

First One :

```
func main() {

  channel := make(chan int)
  go demo(channel)
  num := <-channel
  println(num)

}

func demo(channel chan int) {
  channel <- 2
}
```

Second One:

```
func main() {
    demo()
}

func demo() {
    channel := make(chan int)
    channel <- 2
    num := <-channel
    println(num)
}
```

In the second one, I am taking the input from the channel in the demo function but it still creates a deadlock can someone explain this in brief.
What I can see is when I am calling the channel in the same scope it's causing an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, write to channel is in a separate goroutine. When the main goroutine blocks reading from the channel, there is still one goroutine that can write to the channel, thus is it not a deadlock. Eventually that goroutine writes to the channel and the program completes.

In the second case, write to channel blocks, and there are no other goroutines running, so it is a deadlock.

Comment: By blocking reading from the channel u mean to say that when another thread is spawned (demo). This statement seems a bit weird to me , please help me out .

Comment: Reading from an unbuffered channel blocks until another goroutine writes to it. Writing to an unbuffered channel blocks until another goroutine reads from it. In the first case, you have two goroutines, and they both continue when channel write-read happens. In the second case, there is no second goroutine, and channel write blocks forever.

Comment: So what I can understand is that as we are trying to pause the thread on which we are expecting input from a channel. and as the thread pauses that current thread will not be able to proceed further so a deadlock will occur in the second case as the current thread is paused. Kind of like turning off your own switch if I am a robot.

Answer (score 5):

Your channel is unbuffered so writing to it will block since no other goroutines can read from it.

Make this change and it will run:

```
channel := make(chan int, 1)
```

Comment: I know the way around but I want to know the reason for failing the above code. @colm.anseo

Comment: Channels work best when there's more than one goroutine: typically producer & consumer goroutines. In your second example there is only one goroutine - so only one thread of execution. As such the code using an unbuffered channel cannot both write to & read from the channel without causing deadlock. Making the channel buffer works around this. But as I mentioned, the more idiomatic use case is to have 2 goroutines, as in the first code snippet.

Comment: So what I can understand is that as we are trying to pause the thread on which we are expecting input from a channel. and as the thread pauses that current thread will not be able to proceed further so a deadlock will occur in the second case as the current thread is paused. Kind of like turning off your own switch if I am a robot.